# Is there a way to make r.js make faster compilations?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, gulp, r.js

I'm using **require.js** for modularization and **gulp** with **r.js** for build automation. I've being trying to speedup the build time of my modules, but I have no clue about how to make **r.js** build only the modules whose dependencies have changed.

I know that I can use **gulp-cache** or **gulp-new** to skip all the compilation, but one small file may change and that would trigger all modules compilation. Another option is to break the compilation per module, but to reach a good optimization I must check each related file per module before compilation, very explicit.

Is there another way to optimize this compilation?